# How to make navbar in Bootstrap always stays collapsed, no matter the screen size?

Tags: css, navbar, bootstrap-5, collapsable

how can I to make my navbar in bootstrap always stays/shows collapsed, no matter the screen size? I'm using bootstrap, and when my screen size is bigger, the navbar is displayed automatically, and I want no matter the screen size, the navbar shows collapsed. Thanks

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise to show some code in a minimal example. You can create a demo snippet using the editor.

Comment: Also see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors. "For navbars that never collapse, add the .navbar-expand class on the navbar. For navbars that always collapse, don’t add any .navbar-expand class."

Answer (score 0):

to keep the navbar collapsed on all screen sizes you just need to change the `class=" navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary"`  to

```
class="navbar bg-body-tertiary"
```

this will keep the navbar collapsed on all screen sizes.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="p-3 m-0 border-0 bd-example">

    <!-- Example Code -->
    
    <nav class="navbar bg-body-tertiary">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="d-flex" role="search">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    <!-- End Example Code -->
  </body>
</html>
```